# Basic grep/awk help - extracting all lines containing a list of terms from one file into a separate file

Tags: awk, grep

I have two files `genelist.txt` and `data.txt`. `genelist.txt` simply contains a single column of ~500 gene names, whereas `data.txt` is a tab delimited file that contains ~1000 columns (the samples) and ~30,000 rows (gene names). The general scheme of `data.txt` is outlined below.

`Sample 1    Sample 2    Sample 3    Sample 4 
Gene A      1.04       1.81        1.92        0.45    
Gene B      1.11       1.12        1.32        0.92    
Gene C      0.72       0.71        0.85        1.12    
Gene D      1.19       1.42        0.13        0.32`

I need to extract each row (the entire row, i.e. all samples) from `data.txt` containing each of the ~500 gene names in `genelist.txt` and have these rows extracted to a separate file. I've been told to use grep or awk and have looked into how to do this, however as a simple biologist with little/no coding experience I'm having a bit of trouble. Would it be possible for someone to explain how this is done, and hopefully provide some code for me to get underway.

It would also be neat if the extraction returned only terms that match the entire gene name in `genelist.txt`. For example, if I had **ABC123** but not **ABC1234** in `genelist.txt`, I would want only **ABC123** to be extracted and not **ABC1234**.

Furthermore, after this is done how would I then check to see which of my genes from `genelist.txt` were not included in the extraction? (i.e. some genes may be incorrectly named, so I would have to go back and re-extract them with their alternative and/or correct name).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To extract the lines from `data.txt` with the genes listed in `genelist.txt`:

```
grep -w -F -f genelist.txt data.txt > newdata.txt
```

`grep` options used:

- `-w` tells `grep` to match whole words only (i.e. so `ABC123` won't also match `ABC1234`).
- `-F` search for fixed strings (plain text) rather than regular expressions
- `-f genelist.txt` read search patterns from the file

If you want the header (Sample 1, Sample 2, etc) line as well:

```
grep -w -F -f genelist.txt -e Sample data.txt > newdata.txt
```

- `-e Sample` also search for "Sample"

To find lines in `genelist.txt` that aren't in `newdata.txt`:

```
grep -v -w -F -f <(sed -E -e 's/(\t|  +).*//' newdata.txt) genelist.txt
```

- `-v` invert the search, print non-matching lines.

The rest of the grep options are the same, but instead of using a file with the `-f` option, it's using something called [Process Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) (See [also](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)), which allows you to use a command in place of an actual file.  Whatever output the command creates is treated as the "file"'s contents.

In this case, we're using the command `sed -E -e 's/(\t|  +).*//' newdata.txt`, which outputs each line of newdata.txt after first deleting everything from either the first TAB character or the first pair of spaces it sees.  In other words, the first field (e.g. "Gene A").  I had to use TAB or double space because a) i wasn't sure if your data was space-separated or TAB separated and b) the first fields in your example contained spaces.

`sed` options used:

- `-E` use extended regular expressions, so we can use plain `(`, `)`, and `+` which are more readable than having to escape them with `\` as `\(`, `\)`, `\+`.
- `-e 's/(\t|  +).*//'` specifies the sed script to apply against the input (newdata.txt)

Running that command on your sample `data.txt` would produce the following output:

```
$ sed -E -e 's/(\t|  +).*//' data.txt

Gene A
Gene B
Gene C
Gene D
```

Anyway, the output of that `sed` command is used as the list of search patterns by the `grep` command.

Comment: Thanks! I took a subset of data (about 20 rows) and created a genelist.txt with some of the genes included in the subset of data to play around with (data.txt is 1gb), however using your grep function the new data.txt was just a copy of data.txt. I thought maybe it was something to do with the files (they're both tab delimited, any problem there?), so I tried using csv files instead (data.csv, genelist.csv and newdata.csv) and this worked however it was only showing the last match of the grep (i.e. if genelist.csv contained genes ABC & DEF, it would only show matches for DEF).

Comment: are the genes in genelist.txt listed one per line (they should be)?  or did the file come from an MS-DOS/Windows box? (convert with `fromdos` or `dos2unix` or `tr -d '\r'`).   BTW, tab-delimited is fine.

Comment: I successfully grep'd the list! I think it might have had something to do with the data.txt - I re-downloaded the file and your function worked fine. The genes in genelist.txt were one per line - I created it in excel and converted it to .txt. I was using the default mac text editor for opening the files, so maybe something became misaligned in it (I have since downloaded textwrangler and use that instead).

Comment: I will try the second part (finding the missing genes) this afternoon and report back!

Comment: good to hear.  BTW, if your data files are TAB delimited, you can use `cut -f1 newdata.txt` instead of the `sed` command.  `cut` defaults to using TAB as delimiter.

Comment: Whenever I try to use grep including -v it returns "grep: -v: No such file or directory". Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: exactly what command are you typing in?  `-v` has been a `grep` option for decades...i don't recall ever seeing any version of grep without it.

Comment: What I realised from your running your command exactly was that the terms I'm searching for (from genelist.txt) are in the 6th column of my newdata.txt (some other info/identifiers are in columns 1-5 and 7 as well), so I figured I'd try doing the awk command as suggested above and changing it to the 6th column `awk '{ print $6}' newdata.txt > newdatalist.txt` and grep'ing from that `grep -v -w -F -f newdatalist.txt genelist.txt > missinggenes.txt`. This wasn't working, however I just tried it again (copy and pasting it from previously) and it now worked - weird. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

To actually answer your question:

```
fgrep -w -f genelist.txt data.txt >results.txt
```

- `fgrep` looks for fixed strings, rather than regular expressions (as `grep` and `egrep` do)
- `-w` tells `fgrep` to match whole words, so `ABC123` won't match `ABC1234`
- `-f genelist.txt` tells `fgrep` to read search patterns from `genelist.txt`.

Seeing which genes from `genelist.txt` were not included in the extraction is a little more complicated.  One way to do it:

```
awk '{ print $1 }' results.txt | fgrep -w -v -f - genelist.txt >outsiders.txt
```

- `awk '{ print $1 }'` prints the first column in a text file; these is the list of matched genes
- `fgrep` again matches fixed strings
- `-w` tells `fgrep` to match whole words
- `-v` tells it to print lines that **don't** match
- `-f -` tells it to read the list of patterns from `stdin`, that is the list of matched genes from `awk`.

You can also make things a little more efficient by eliminating duplicates from the list of matched genes before searching, by interceding `sort -u` between `awk` and `fgrep`:

```
awk '{ print $1 }' results.txt | sort -u | fgrep -w -v -f - genelist.txt >outsiders.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and like I said in a comment to @Cas, the results.txt file was just a copy of the data.txt file. I tried using csv formats instead of tab delimited .txt - this worked but was only displaying the last match (i.e. if I had genes ABC, DEF and GHI, only the matches for GHI would be in the results.csv file). Any more help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DiscoA One possible explanation for what you're describing would be if your files have DOS line endings while your `grep`, `awk`, etc. expect UNIX line endings.  If that's the case, you need to convert the files with `dos2unix`, or whatever it's called these days.  Something like `sed -i 's/\r//' *.txt` might work, too.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I re-downloaded the data.txt file and tried the function again and it worked. I was using the default mac text editor to open files (maybe something became accidentily misaligned when I had it open), and I created the genelist.txt file in excel, so yep I think you're right in it being some formatting issue. I have since downloaded textwrangler to make things unix-friendly. I will try the second part this afternoon (finding the missing genes) and report back, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite an undertaking without any previous Linux experience. However, I think I understand what you need, and it shouldn't be too difficult. PArdon me in advance, this is a very concise crash course in addition to a very basic explanation but I'd be happy to expound in detail if it doesn't make sense, or edit as necessary.

If you simply want to parse the `data.txt` and move it to the `genelist.txt` you could simply use `cat data.txt >> genelist.txt newfile.txt`. (newfile.txt is the other file you mentioned it going to - the name is arbitrary).

If you want to print out the lines for a specific name, you could use `cat data.txt | grep ABCD123 >> genelist.txt newfile.txt` and change ABCD123 to whatever you want.

This command will ONLY output the lines found using grep (kind of like a "search" function, but it searches only by line.)

The "|" is called piping, and when coupled with "grep" command, acts a little like a filter for whatever you're looking for. (`cat zoofile.txt | grep pandas` for instance will look for all lines including the word "pandas" is a file names "zoofile." Note Linux IS CASE SENSITIVE and will only find EXACTLY what you put in. If you want ALL instances of either "panda, pandas, panderoons, or pandering, you could use pand*, where * is a wildcard and could be any character from 0 to 255 bits in length. This would pick up pand to pandzzzzzzzzzz and anything in between, including numbers).

You can use awk for more fancy column parsing (it's one of my favorite tools!) but it doesn't seem like it would fit here unless you ONLY want data from one of the columns based on certain parameters.

Finally, here is a good place to learn a bit about the command line. This may help with grep, but it doesn't cover awk.

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-the-command-line

After that, this should cover awk in more detail. There are a lot of VERY expansive courses on awk, but they're easy to get lost in. This is a practical site that demonstrates more what you're looking to do.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-awk1/

EDIT - after re-reading, I may have missed something - are you looking to compare the two files and print out only things that match from one to the other? Please advise and provide an example and I'd be happy to edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes, I'm looks to compare the files and print out only the lines from data.txt that contain the terms in genelist.txt.